# The name 'changetype' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am new in ASP.net /c# coding. I have a Gridview in my usercontrol with this column

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Parameter Order">
     <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="orderlbl" runat="server"  Text='<%# changetype(Eval("PARAM_ORDER")) %>' ></asp:Label>

     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

the param_order is int. I have defined the Changetype in cs file as

```
public string changetype(object order)
{
    string lcResult = "";
    int itemOrder = (int)order;
    lcResult = itemOrder.ToString().TrimEnd();
    return lcResult;
}
```

but I get the above error message.

Comment: Can you post the page declaration?    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

Answer (score 0):

try doing it in this way:

```
((Label)e.Item.FindControl("orderlbl")).Text= changetype(Eval("PARAM_ORDER"));
```

Comment: The error has changed to a very odd one  ASP.forms_admin_param_aspx.GetTypeHashCode()': no suitable method found to override

Comment: why not doing it server side, it is much better since it won't do late binding

Comment: no suitable method found to override??  I don't understand why it can not connect to my cs file??

Comment: What do you mean as server side? you mean in javascript?

Comment: i edited my answer, the above should work now. don't forget to check if the item type is Dataitem

Answer (score 0):

change your procedure to protected

```
protected string changetype(object order) 
{ 
    string lcResult = ""; 
    int itemOrder = (int)order; 
    lcResult = itemOrder.ToString().TrimEnd(); 
    return lcResult; 
}
```